# Import error of Cephes Scipy library within WinPython

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to test the [WinPython environment](http://code.google.com/p/winpython/), a portable Python environment, in order to create a version featuring more packages.

I'm working in Windows Vista 32 bit (but the underlying CPU is 64 bit), Service Pack 2, Python 2.7.3, Scipy 0.11 in WinPython-32bit-2.7.3.1 and Scipy 0.10.1 in WinPython-32bit-2.7.3.0.

I have the same problem with both WinPython-32bit-2.7.3.1.exe and previous WinPython-32bit-2.7.3.0.exe versions, trying multiple downloads of the installers, different installations in different folders (without spaces in pathnames).

When I do the unit testing from Scipy with:

```
scipy.test()
```

I get 8 errors, all related to the failed import of the Cephes library (_cephes.pyd file). 
The typical error message is:

```
packages\scipy\special__init__.py", line 525, in 
   from _cephes import * 
ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata.
```

The distribution creator is not able to reproduce the error in a similar environment, and a co-worker has no problems (in Win 7, 64 bit).

I have also [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) (non-portable environment, from the same author) installed, where everything is ok, and I don't remember to ever had a similar problem with Python/Scipy with non-portable installations.

Thank you for any hint/suggestion.

Comment: I believe that opening a bug report would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

fyi i also had the problem,  downgraded to 0.9, and it works.

**edit:**

I searched all over, and asside from numerous other people having the exact same problem with 0.10.x,  no solutions have been posted.  See here:  http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2012-February/031527.html and more generally here: https://www.google.com/search?q=cephes+dll+load+failed

This leads me to try either downgrading to 0.9.x or upgrading...  my distro doesn't provide beyond 0.10.1, but the downgrade works.